# Why did my answer go "community-wiki" on me? I only edited it twice(!)

Tags: discussion, reputation, community-wiki

I thought you had to edit an answer 10 times to promote it into being community wiki...

My answer went community wiki after only 2 edits. 
Seems a bit eager to me. Considering leaving my spelling mistakes in there if this is how the rules work ;-)

Here's the example:

[Busting Ruby on Rails Myths](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1741598/busting-ruby-on-rails-myths/1743599#1743599)

edited twice...

Comment: Can you link to the answer?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The OP made the topic CW 10 hours ago, you posted your answer 4 hours ago.

Any answer posted in a CW topic is automatically CW.

Comment: Thanks for that, but does "OP" mean moderator?

Comment: OP = Original Poster